# Implement UICollectionViewDataSource methods with reactivecocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, reactive-cocoa

I am trying to learn RAC, and I've already seen how one can implement delegate methods using `rac_signalForSelector`. I am using a `UICollectionView` to display some data, and I've handled all the necessary `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods using this solution. For example, here is  a `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` implementation:

```
[[weakSelf rac_signalForSelector:@selector(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:) fromProtocol:@protocol(UICollectionViewDelegate)] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *arguments) {
        __strong MainViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = arguments.second;
        DetailViewModel *viewModel = [[DetailViewModel alloc] initWithModel:strongSelf.viewModel.model[indexPath.item]];
        DetailViewController *viewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithViewModel:viewModel];
        [strongSelf.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}];
```

I am wondering if it is possible to implement `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods like this as well, since they also have return values.

Comment: I've asket for similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492229/datasource-methods-with-racsignals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer - **NO**

Reactive Cocoa is a reactive framework and you should design your app logic in a reactive way not proactive. It means that you should react to some events and do something about it.
As an example - user click on a cell and you get an RAC event, you can manipulate that event (map, filter, combine with other events and etc).

It not possible because Reactive Cocoa is designed for **push-based API** for composing and transforming streams of values.